# My dynamically added event listeners attach (using the exact same html) on a small screen size, but not on a big one

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, addeventlistener

I built a small website and dynamically add the code to html `divs`. After the data has been set, I add a `click` event and `mouse enter/leave` event using the `id` of the `div`. It is just plain **HTML**, **javascript** and **css**.

When I open the page on a small screen size, the events attach, but when I resize the screen or open on a large size the events do not attach.

I have also tried using both the `id` and the `class` selector. The result is the same. I also tried setting the event listener based on the update of the screen size (media query). The html and css is only set once - on load.

I thought that the problem might be happening because of a timeout? How is it best to troubleshoot this?

**Javascript**

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass');

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)").matches) {
                /* The viewport is less than, or equal to, 800 pixels wide */
                console.log(at 800+"this works, but");
              } else {
                /* The viewport is greater than 800 pixels wide */
                    console.log("this is not working");
                    [...elements].forEach( (el) => {
                        el.addEventListener('click', masterEventHandler, false);
                        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', inFunction, false);
                        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', outFunction, false);
                    });
              }
```

and this is the the setup code I used for the container (note I left out one or two divs - it is just to illustrate):

```
function display(id){

        var container = document.getElementById("myContainer");
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        var containedElement = document.createElement("div");

        element.id = id;
        element.className = "myClass";
        containedElement.className = "tohideStuffOnLoad";

        element.appendChild(containedElement);
        container.appendChild(element);

}
```

The following is my code after it compiled. This remains the same for the lifetime of the page for the lifetime of the app:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="id" class="inner">
<div id="amnt" class="amount">$43,762.00</div>
<div class="h-overlay m-display">This is the title
<div class="img"><span>▶</span></div>
</div>
<img src="/animage.jpg" alt="my-image">
<div class="ribbon-new"><img src="/new-ribbon.png" alt="ribbon"></div></div>
</div>
```

I clicked on inspect element and I watched my html - the m-display property toggles on a screen size 800 and smaller and does nothing on a large screen size.

No errors show except for the fact that my events are not firing.

```
On asking for extra code, I present to you my Event Listeners (I reviewed everything - it is just standard javascript in a script tag):

var inFunction = function(event){
        //console.log(event);
        event.target.children[1].classList.remove("m-display");
    };

    var outFunction = function(event){
        //console.log(event);
        event.target.children[1].classList.add("m-display");
     };

     var masterEventHandler = function(e){
         console.log("Here I redirect to some other stuff");
     };
```

note the above, although I don't think it changes anything

Comment: Can you show some more code? Which elements are we talking about that you assign the events to?

Comment: can you make a simple code pen ?

Comment: I changed it because I realised I made a mistake before, so I fixed it @MrLister

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so here is what went wrong:

The background property of the parent container was transparent.
The z-index was set above content below;
The container was covering content below it.
This was only set for the large screen...
Thus no click methods were firing for content below it :(

Luckily nothing wrong with my Javascript. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Can this question be closed now, or do you want to leave it open for future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass');
```

Snapshots all `div.myClass` elements. What is possibly happening is that after refresh different elements are added to `.myContainer`, ones that weren't snapshotted.

You could try refreshing the list above on resize.

Comment: The elements do not change after load... Only the classes

Comment: Problem is none of the elements have the event listeners attached when the screen width is > 800px and all of them have them attached when they are <800px.

Comment: I tried refreshing the list too. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/rzj8wtvk/3/) based on your source, but it seems to work as designed, also at 800px and above. So something elst must be going on.

Comment: when my screen width is bigger than 800px my events are still not firing... the window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)").matches was actually just an illustration

Comment: I clicked on inspect element and I watched my html - the m-display property toggles on a screen size 800 and smaller and does nothing on a large screen size. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Ok... I used another method to add an eventlistener and the behaviour is the same. If this continues, do I re-install chrome?